# The variable x in this integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to find the volume of a torus, and I got everything right except for the *x* variable that the book uses and I have no idea where they got that *x* from. Can someone explain this to me? (Note the *x* with the red ring on it)[image])

Comment: That would be a shell integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! :) The way to look at that $x$ value, is it is the radius of the torus at the point of integration. You are doing integration by means of shells, which has a general form of:
$$\int 2\pi x*y(x)dx$$
Imagine peeling the paper label off a can, and laying it flat. It has height $y$, and length $2\pi r$, where $r$ is the radius of the can. Thus, it has surface area of: $2\pi yr$. If you integrate (add up) all the concentric paper shells that would fit inside the can, you obtain the volume of the can itself ($\pi r^2y$).

Let's verify this:
$$V=\pi r^2 y = \int_0^r 2\pi x*y(x)dx = 2\pi\int_0^rx*ydx=2\pi y \left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_0^r=\pi y r^2$$

Comment: by "radius of the torus" do you mean total radius, i.e. major radius + minor radius? as in from the centre of the torus to point (b+a)?

Comment: Center of the torus to the circle about the $z\hat$ axis. At the outside edge of the torus, it will be $b+a$. Notice how integration starts at the minimum radius of the torus, which is $b-a$. I think your convention and my convention are slightly different, which is leading to confusion.